# How to convert class to it's child in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class called `class_A` I do some work with it and store it with `pickle`.
I have another class `class_B` which is a child of `class_A` but has some additional methods and properties. I want to load data from my pickled file as `class_B` and work with it. How can I do it?

Comment: Some code as an example of what you're trying to achieve wouldn't hurt. Generally speaking, you can _update_ your `class_B` instance's `__dict__` with the one from an unpickled `class_A` but that won't work at all times and is generally a bad practice. You should just make `class_B` recognize `class_A` as an input and handle the update itself.

Comment: There is probably no general way, and you'll have to cook something up yourself. More details would be helpful to formulating an answer. Also - *always* use the generic Python tag, and a version-specific tag optionally.

Answer (score 2):

You could override the unpickler's `find_class` function, like so:

```
import pickle

# Set up class_A and class_B as in the question
class class_A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def method_a(self): pass
class class_B(class_A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b = 1
    def method_b(self): pass

# Create an pickle a class_A object
a = class_A()
with open('pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(a, f)

# Create an unpickler that lies about class types
class MyUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def find_class(self, module, name):
        if (module, name) == ('__main__', 'class_A'):
            name = 'class_B'
        return pickle.Unpickler.find_class(self, module, name)

# Unpickle with the transmorgifying unpickler
with open('pickle', 'rb') as f:
    new_b = MyUnpickler(f).load()

# Verify that the returned object is a `class_B`
assert isinstance(new_b, class_B)
assert hasattr(new_b, 'method_a')
assert hasattr(new_b, 'method_b')
assert hasattr(new_b, 'a')

# Sadly, new_b.__init__ never ran, so no `new_b.b`
assert not hasattr(new_b, 'b')
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler.find_class

Comment: Not too deep. [It's documented.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler.find_class)

Answer (score 0):

More details around your exact use case are needed to be certain, but  one of these abstract approaches may work for you.

```
b = Class_B()
b.__dict__ = pickled_data
```

Or

```
b = Class_B(**pickled_data)
```

Or

```
a = Class_A()
b = Class_B()
b.__dict__ = a.__dict__
```

I'd recommend crating a class method to do what you need.

```
b = B.from_a(class_a, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: don't use ``` to format blocks of code. stackoverflow has better mechanisms. Just type your code normally, then select it all and click on the `{}` button to indent the entire block. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @brianoakley I'm on my phone.  Those tools are not available.